# How can I use the YouTube search engine API?

Tags: php, google-api, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I find on [Github](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/php) some examples of YouTube API, so for my website I enabled the "YouTube Data API v3" from Google developers console however after upload to my website the code below, I cannot retrieve any videos and I get this error from browser console: "`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`" after click on the search button.

this is my `search.php` file:

```
<?php

$htmlBody = <<<END
<form method="GET">
  <div>
    Search Term: <input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search Term">
  </div>
  <div>
    Max Results: <input type="number" id="maxResults" name="maxResults" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="25">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
END;

if ($_GET['q'] && $_GET['maxResults']) {
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

  $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'my_api_key';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

  try {
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    ));

    $videos = '';
    $channels = '';
    $playlists = '';

    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#video':
          $videos .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['videoId']);
          break;
        case 'youtube#channel':
          $channels .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
          break;
        case 'youtube#playlist':
          $playlists .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['playlistId']);
          break;
      }
    }

    $htmlBody .= <<<END
    <h3>Videos</h3>
    <ul>$videos</ul>
    <h3>Channels</h3>
    <ul>$channels</ul>
    <h3>Playlists</h3>
    <ul>$playlists</ul>
END;
  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>YouTube Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```

What's wrong and why I cannot retrieve YouTube videos?

Comment: What do your server logs say...

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Yea I get that. But, the question is: Is your server giving the 500 or the youtube server giving the 500. My bet is on your server giving the 500 and the error details will be visible in your server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a syntax error in your script. The 500 error is an HTTP status error returned when there is a server side issue that prevents completing the request. It's unlikely the error is coming from the Youtube API.

I don't see an obvious syntax error in that code. You should take a look at your Apache / ngnix / other webserver error log, and go from there and/or post the errors.